# Exporting all functions of a custom package to a file

Tags: r, package

My situation is the following:
I made a package (named MyCDM) with several functions that I constantly use in my applications. When I running the scripts in my PC (I use Rstudio), I include the command `library(MyCDM)` and all works fine.

The problem is that I wanted to migrate the execution of my script to a cloud service of my University, where I don't have the privilege of include new packages.

I want to export all functions of MyCDM package into a single R file, in a way that I can copy this file into the University server and source it in my script.

I know that I could copy the "R" folder of my package and paste it on the destination folder. But the University site guides us to avoid to copy/read/write operations with a large number of small files due to the impact the server's performance.

I was able to import all functions to my global environment, but I don't know how to write the function body's into a file.

There is a way to do it in a simple manner?

*(ps.: English is not my first language. Sorry for any language mistake. If I not made myself clear, please ask for clarification in the comments)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to just use R to copy and paste the contents of each file in the R directory into a new file:

```r
purrr::walk(
  .x = list.files(path = "R/"),
  .f = ~write(
    readLines(file.path("R", .x)),
    file = "functions_script.R",
    append = TRUE)
)
```

This gets a list of all files in the R directory (assuming your working directory is currently the root of the package, although you could easily change this) using `list.files`. Then copies and writes the contents of each file to a new file `functions_script.R`, (and appends each additional file).

Answer (score 1):

You can acess the list of all functions in "MyCDM" with `lsf.str("package:MyCDM")`. Then, you can pass that to `dump()` to save it all in a R. file:

```
dump(lsf.str("package:MyCDM"), file="MyCDM functions.R")
```

Later, you just need to do

```
source("MyCDM functions.R")
```

And all your functions will be loaded in your global enviroment.

Comment: Great solution. I already accept the answer of @nrennie, but your approach it also works fine! Three comments: (1) It worth to mention that the package must be loaded before the "dump" in order this approach to work properly; (2) the accepted solution has the advantage of also copy the comments presented in the function files; (3) your approach has the advantage to also works in CRAN packages (I tested for some of them).